# Search box not showing post list

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I'm hoping you can help me with an issue that I can't solve.
When I updated `wordpress` to the latest version, `select2` lost the functionality to show the latest posts.

[image]

The above image is the example of what is happening. Instead it should **search and show a list of the last posts by default**, without the need to write anything.

The `javascript` code that we built to circumvent the situation should correct this behaviour, but the trigger is not working properly and only works when a key is pressed inside the box.

**Question:** Has anyone ever had this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var select2_open;
    // open select2 dropdown on focus
    $(document).on('focus', '.select2-selection--single', function (e) {

        select2_open = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('select');
        $('.select2-search__field').val(' ');
        // trigger keydown event, currently not working
            $('.select2-search__field').trigger('keyup.search');

    });


});
```

Comment: Can you try `$( URCLASSNAME ).keyup();` instead of `trigger`

Comment: it's working !! Thank you for your help.